# PHP exec using LP command fails on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, osx-lion

I am trying to spool a file to a printer attached to the server using PHP.

I send a command such as `lp -d 'Brother_QL-570'  '/Users/user_name/Documents/wwwroot/mmsprint/mmsUw8Vv9` using EXEC in PHP and get a return value of `5`. The command works fine in the terminal window.

If I send `ls`, `whoami` etc, the command executes fine.

`whoami` and `ls` live in /bin, so I created a symbolic link for lp and that made no difference.

Also tried `/usr/bin/lp` and that did not work either. I'm pulling what little hair I have left out over this.

Safe mode is off. The path variables are the same between PHP and my terminal environment.
I am running MAMP on Lion.

FWIW, the command `cat /Users/user_name/Documents/wwwroot/mmsprint/mmswKJqYK | lp -d Brother_QL-570` has a return value of `133`.

This is my code:

```
$temp_file = tempnam("./", 'mms');
$pdf->Output($temp_file, "F");
$pdf->Close();
$cmd = "lp -d 'Brother_QL-570'  '".$temp_file."'";
exec($cmd,$output,$retval);
error_log("-----cmd=".$cmd."\n", 3, "printCard.log");
foreach ($output as $a) {
    error_log("-----output=".$a."\n", 3, "printCard.log");
}
error_log("-----retval=".$retval."\n", 3, "printCard.log");
```

Any thoughts? What am I missing? This should be easy. Argh!!

Comment: Please don't revert edits that were done to improve the readability of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the output from the command?

Most likely the PHP user (apache probably) has no permission to print things. Add that user to the lp group. (Assuming macs work similar to unix in this.)

Comment: He's running MAMP, so I'd assume that the apache user isn't used.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Macs don't have the apache process run as a different user?

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt According to http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/1329 it's the `www` user. So add `www` to the group `lp`.

Comment: @Both: he's running MAMP, not the built-in server

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be a problem with MAMP. I googled "MAMP exec fails" and came up with several good answers. Its a compatibility problem with libraries. I added `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='' &&` to the command and Bob's my uncle. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar solution to the one mentioned about using `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='' &&`.  Using this worked for me, so I tried to find a more permanent fix than including this in all my code.  I opened up the file `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars` and commented the following two lines out:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

After restarting apache, this is working GREAT! Not sure why this is happening to me though.  Might have to do something with the fact that I am running 2 virtual hosts.